# How do I configure HK2 to inject an object created by a factory method?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, hk2

In HK2 the basic example code for configuring injection is this (within a class that extends `AbstractBinder`:

```
bind(BuilderHelper
    .link(FooImpl.class)    // the class of the object to be injected
    .to(FooInterface.class) // identifies what @Inject fields to link to
    .build());
```

This causes HK2 to call the constructor `FooImpl()` when it needs to create a `FooInterface`.

What if FooImpl doesn't have a constructor?

- What if it's intended to be instantiated with a static factory method `FooImpl.getInstance()`
- What if it's intented to be instantiated by a factory object `fooFactory.create()`

I see that `ResourceConfig` has a method `bind(FactoryDescriptors factoryDescriptors)` but it is not clear to me what the idiom is for building a `FactoryDescriptors` object, and have not been able to find any examples online.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I still can't see a way to do it using the BuilderHelper EDSL (it appears this is overkill for the common case too), the following works:

```
  bindFactory(FooFactory.class)
       .to(FooInterface.class);
```

This requires that `FooFactory` is an implementation of `Factory<FooInterface>`, so you need a facade around any existing factory you have. I did it as a private inner class where I needed it.

```
 private static class FooFactory implements Factory<FooInterface> {

    @Override
    public void dispose(FooInterface foo) {
      // meh
    }

    @Override
    public FooInterface provide() {
      return SomeFactory.getInstance();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What if it's a 3rd party class that does not implement any interface? I.e. there's only `Foo`, no `FooInterface`.

Answer (score 4):

Currently hk2 only supports the Factory interface for creating objects with special constructor needs.  We have been considering adding a static method constructor or doing some sort of CDI @Produces type of mechanism.  It is difficult to decide which of these things is worth the extra complexity (we try very hard to stay light-weight).

I think in your code example above your private static class needs to implement the Factory interface, right?

Comment: FWIW I think it's fine how it is, but the HK2 documentation needs some examples of it in use.

Comment: I have added this bug https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-167 to track adding more examples concerning factories.  Other people have had problems using the EDSL with factories as well, so I think it is a common problem