# Jersey dependency injection not working

Tags: rest, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm trying to inject a dependency to my Rest service controller which used Jersey to implement,
This is my Controller

```
@Path("service")
public class ServiceProviderController {
 @Inject
 private ServiceProviderService prov;

 public ServiceProviderController(){}

 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 Public ServiceProviders testService(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    prov.getName(name);
    return name;
 }
```

This is the binder class

```
   import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
   import com.api.controller.ServiceProviderController;
   import com.api.service.ServiceProviderService;
    public class APIBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {   
      bindAsContract(ServiceProviderService.class).to(ServiceProviderController.class);
    } }
```

This is the application class

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication(){
        register(new APIBinder());
        packages(true, "com.api.service");
    }
}
```

I'm calling this from the main method like this

```
MyApplication app = new MyApplication();
```

The error is

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ServiceProviderService,parent=ServiceProviderController,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,912348460)
```

Please help me to get this fixed,

Thanks a lot

Ero

Added a factory implementation, still not get fixed same error pops up

```
    public class APIBinder extends AbstractBinder implements Factory<ServiceProviderService> {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bindFactory(this).to(ServiceProviderService.class);
    }

    public ServiceProviderService provide() {
        ServiceProviderService sp= new ServiceProviderService();
        return sp;
    }

    public void dispose(ServiceProviderService instance) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `.to(ServiceProviderController.class);`

Comment: Removed still not works

Comment: Do you have any web.xml configuration? Just wondering if your `MyApplication` class is even being used. Can you confirm this?

Comment: No i'm running the application with Grizzly server, so there is a main method to start, inside it i have placed 'MyApplication app = new MyApplication()' object creation

Answer (score -1):

You can create a factory. See this thread for explanation.

[How do I configure HK2 to inject an object created by a factory method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123326/how-do-i-configure-hk2-to-inject-an-object-created-by-a-factory-method)

Comment: Add factory implementation as above but still not get fixed same error occurred